# What is the meaning of Scan Speed in case of a mass spectrometer?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

For example if the scan speed is $15000 \frac{u}{s}$ then what does it mean? Since $u$ is a mass unit, then does $15000 \frac{u}{s}$ mean that the Mass Spec is able to scan mass of $15000$ per second?

Comment: If you set it to scan 1 to 300u repeatedly it can do that 50 times per second.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?q=http://tools.thermofisher.com/content/sfs/brochures/PSB-119-Scan-Speed-vs-Cycle-Time-on-an-Ion-Trap-Mass-Spectrometer.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjtsOHhhIr5AhVWIEQIHfCuCAMQFXoECAQQBQ&usg=AOvVaw3wrnzaLcQWasiAx3ECb98i